# How to monitor kafka system metrics like CPU load and memory usage?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, grafana, metrics

I've enabled both exporters:

- kafka-exporter
- kafka-jmx-exporter

**chart.yaml:**

```
...
dependencies:
  ...
  - name: kafka
    version: 17.1.0
    repository: "@bitnami"
    condition: kafka.enabled
  ...
```

**values.yaml:**

```
kafka:
  metrics:
    kafka:
      enabled: true
    jmx:
      enabled: true
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: true
      labels:
        my.custom.label/service-monitor: "1.0"
```

I see that both of them are appeared on status->Service Discovery page of Prometheus so I consider them working.

Next step: I add following grafana dashboard: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/12483

But most of metrics(not all) are not available on that dashboard.
[image]
For example one of the panel uses `jvm_memory_bytes_used` metric but I don't see this metric on prometheus side

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

CPU and memory load would need to come from a different exporter (e.g. [`node_exporter`](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter))  or for related pod/container metrics within k8s, then `cAdvisor`.

> For example one of the panel uses `jvm_memory_bytes_used` metric but I don't see this metric on prometheus side

Unclear what Datasource your Grafana dashboard is using. If it is Prometheus, then you will want to first ensure you are querying within the appropriate time range. But only after you manually grep the metrics endpoint that is being scraped to ensure your JMX exporter is actually reporting that data.

Comment: you are rign Grafana uses prometheus as a datasource.

Comment: Could you please a bit more details about  node_exporter + cAdvisor configuration?

Do they work only together ?

Comment: `node_exporter` would show the infrastructure details of the hosts where  `kubelet` is running. `cAdvisor` would show Kafka (and other) container metrics. Ideally, you'd have Prometheus server(s) running outside of the k8s cluster for it all to work, however, `prom-operator` can be deployed within and `remote_scrape` can externally point at the instance(s) within the cluster.

Comment: [This chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) includes node exporter and `kube-state-metrics` and you'd then add `ServiceMonitor` definitions for the JMX exporter services

Comment: we already use kube-prometheus-stack. but my prometheus is running inside the cluster.
I would appreciate if you can provide high level step by step instructure

Comment: I don't have a full example. [The question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193780/how-can-prometheus-operator-be-configured-to-collect-from-cadvisor-on-kubernetes) seems to be related to what you want